# Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a boolean checkbox, when I debug I get the error that the specified cast is not valid. What have I done wrong?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="spam"  <%if ((bool) ViewData["spam"])     Response.Write("checked"); %><%if (teststring.Length==0) Response.Write("disabled"); %>/> Check here if you want to receive junk mail (spam).
```

Thank you

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="spam"  <%if ((bool) ViewData["spam"])     Response.Write("checked"); %><%if (teststring.Length==0) Response.Write("disabled"); %>/> Check here if you want to receive junk mail (spam). 

Thank you

Comment: What have you put in `ViewData["spam"]`? It would have to be a boolean value to be possible to unbox it like that.

Comment: Could this be the problem on home controller...  if (mypatient.spam == true)
                    {
                        ViewData["spam"] = "Y";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewData["spam"] = "N";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that you set not boolean value to ViewData["spam"] (or even don't set it). To handle this situation write next code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="spam"  
    <%if (ViewData["spam"] is bool && (bool) ViewData["spam"]) Response.Write("checked"); %>
    <%if (teststring.Length==0) Response.Write("disabled"); %>/> 
Check here if you want to receive junk mail (spam).
```

Remember that you have to set ViewData["spam"] manually.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use 
    'Convert.ToBoolean(ViewData["spam"])'
instead of
     bool) ViewData["spam"]

Comment: 'Convert.ToBoolean will too give exception if casting fails.

Comment: It will not fail, because Convert.ToBoolean(object) can receive a null. See the referrence http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh2c31dd.aspx

Comment: what if ViewData["spam"]="abc"? will it cast successfully?

Comment: No it will not. Because when such assignment happens, the object casting to string and implicit conversation taking place. And if value was null, CLR will failed to cast. But in the question Item["spam"] used only in if condition and I suggested to tell to the CLR that it's bool value

Answer (score 0):

`Casting error` occurs if you want to cast `some value` to `specific type` which is `incompatible`, for example, if you want to case `abc` to `bool` it will `throw exception`. One reason of your `exception` could be that `ViewData["spam"]` could be `null` or contains value thats `not compatible` with `boolean` type. You could do

```
<input type="checkbox" name="spam"  <%if (ViewData["spam"]!=null && (bool) ViewData["spam"])     Response.Write("checked"); %><%if (teststring.Length==0) Response.Write("disabled"); %>/> Check here if you want to receive junk mail (spam).
```

Answer (score 0):

Either put the boolean value in the view data:

```
ViewData["spam"] = mypatient.spam;
```

Or check for the string:

```
<%= ViewData["spam"].ToString() == "Y" ? "checked" : "" %>
```